# CameraUpdateFactory zoom not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

```
private void setCurrentLocationMarker(LatLng currLatLng) {
    if (currLatLng == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currLatLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(R.integer.camera_zoom_value));
    setMarkerAtCentre(mMap.getCameraPosition().target);
}

private void setMarkerAtCentre(LatLng cameraCentre){
    if(cameraCentre == null) return;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(cameraCentre);
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
    markerOptions.title("Your Position");
    sourceMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

Above two are the functions for setting the marker to desired latitude and longitude and placing the camera focusing the location.
Everything is working fine.
But the problem which I face here is with the zoom

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(R.integer.camera_zoom_value));
```

I may place any value for the zoom.

```
<integer name="camera_zoom_value">2</integer>
```

But the zoom which I get always is the maximum one i.e. the largest possible zoom, which is kinda issue here.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

your are passing the resource integer directly without using getResources().getInteger() so the value passed is some long integer > 20 leading to maximum zoom. Fix that and it will work.